# Jenkins cannot open directory Permission denied

Tags: jenkins

I am using Jenkins to 'execute shell' command

```
ls -l /mnt/ftpbackup/ftpuser/*
```

But getting error

```
ls: cannot open directory /mnt/ftpbackup/ftpuser/: Permission denied
```

I am able to run the very same command when I log as 'jenkins' user, see below:

```
-bash-4.1$ id
uid=493(jenkins) gid=490(jenkins) groups=490(jenkins),504(ftpuser) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
-bash-4.1$ ls -l /mnt/ftpbackup/ftpuser
total 48116044
....
```

Comment: Just to verify , what is the "started by user" ? jenkins ? you can find the same in console log of the failed jenkins build.

Comment: I dont see user name on console log, except [workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /var/lib/jenkins/tmp/hudson4869177118530409607.sh

Comment: you could find the same outside console log also , click on build number on left side build history ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you trying to execute this command in the jenkins master through jenkins?

try whoami command to find out which user jenkins is using to execute commands

if you are executing in any node, the jenkins will connect to that node using the credentials you have provided in node settings, please check that.

Comment: Right I am trying to execute this command in the jenkins master, I dont think I provided any credentials for master, should I , how ?

Comment: I found workaround, using plugin to ssh to localhost with non-jenkins credentials instead executing shell in jenkins and it works fine

Comment: pass a command in "execute shell" as "whoami". this way you can find which user jenkins is using.